# retrieving null value from the database table in asp.net mvc 2.0 using c#

Tags: linq-to-sql, null

I have a problem with retrieving the `null` value.

I have a option in my MVC application. If I select Taxable field as *Yes* then entered value is stored in the table.  If I select Taxable as *No* then `Null` value is stored in the table.

Now I want to retrieve that null value from the table to use it for calcution purposes.
This is my coding ,

```
return db.Groups.SingleOrDefault(g => g.GroupID == gid).TaxRate.HasValue ?      
db.Groups.SingleOrDefault(g => g.GroupID == gid).TaxRate.Value : (double?)0.0;
```

But in the first condition only it will shows the error as

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Nullable Object must have a value.
```

I don't know why I got this error.

Please tell me solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set just db.Groups.SingleOrDefault(g => g.GroupID == gid) to a variable, and then checking to see if the TaxRate property exists or is null?

Comment: before i done like this ,but while declaring the variable like, double? tax; here only i got the error.Thats why now i directly returning the taxrate value in the single line.But while checking condition only it shows error .please tell me why it happens.

Comment: Assign it to just an object variable and inspect it in your Visual Studio debugger. Or better yet, look up in the MSDN library what the return type of SingleOrDefault is.